# Can we skip or terminate asynchronous state updates while testing with Jest?

Tags: testing, jestjs

I have a use-case where I have a component with asynchronus(fetch) code in that which causes state updation. I need to test a text, lets say 'test1' which have nothing to do with fetch response and state updation.

I am getting 'cannot perform react state update on unmounted component' warning in the console.

I don't want to waitFor() the fetch response or state updates to happen.

Is there any way in jest so that I can skip the state updates(caused by asynchronus code) or kill the process of state updations after each test.

Comment: One option is to use the deferred pattern to create a promise that resolves when you choose, then choose never to resolve it. That becomes the test double for the promise returned by fetch.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am new to jest. I could not interpret your solution. I have to implement or handle it from the testing file. Could you elaborate your solution if we are in the same lines.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.